# Gnome Shell floating HDD icon

Tags: gnome

Where does the floating hdd icon comes from?

It's obviously from my external HDD, but I don't want to have it there.

Once I click it, it goes away. Is there a way not to show it at all?

[image]

My current extensions based on `Advanced Settings`

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. Do you have any extensions installed that interfere with notifications or the messaging-tray? It would be useful if you can list all your extensions as well.

Comment: I editted the question.

Comment: I have installed all your activated extensions and can't seem to replicate it. Do you experience this issue everytime or was it just an one-off incident? Can you turn off all the extension and check if that solves your problem?

Comment: I will try that. It shows every time I connect some external device, like a flash disk or hdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was caused by bad theme.

When disabling the `User Themes Extension`, everything went back to normal.

Thanks to [@jokerdino](https://askubuntu.com/users/25798/jokerdino) for the headsup. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Well done. Congrats on having it fixed. :)